# How to register Broadcastreceiver for phone startup and on incoming sms in android

Tags: android

My application doesn't have any activity class. So i need to start my application on boot. That is a receiver. this is my menifest file.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <service android:name="com.example.smsbackup.SaveSms"></service>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.smsbackup.IncomingMsg">   
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

I have tried this with activity class then this will work. But i don't need any app icon show. I think this is not working because of the two `action`s. So How can start the receiver on phone startup and on sms receive ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<service android:name="com.example.smsbackup.SaveSms">

    <receiver android:name="com.example.smsbackup.IncomingMsg">   
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.CutomBroadcast"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Use the Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

public class CustomBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    context.startService(new Intent(context, MyOwnService.class));
  }
}
```

Comment: So from where i can get incoming sms fire ? Can u exaplain me with details ?